# How to externally copy an old UFS hard drive?

Tags: solaris, raid, file-copy, sparc

Here at work our machines are required to run off of old Sun Sparc5's (1995) all running a UFS architecture on the hard drives due to a Solaris 5.3ish base. The way they are configured it is not possible (that I have found) to hook up a second SCSI hard drive so that it can recognize it and allow me to do an internal copy. In order to increase reliability of these computers we purchased a raid array with a SCSI to SATA converter inside to write to 2.5" internals. This raid setup has worked successfully on the computers that use IDE type connections, using the same arrays also a UFS architecture.

I have tried an OmniSCSI-One-to-One tool, it properly clipped down the size and copied all the directories but did not move any of the actual data. I was able to read the hard drive after with UFS Explorer and verified the directories were present. Found out when I took it to the machine that it had no data on it.

I have authorization to purchase a computer just for the task of copying and backing up these drives. What OS or program would be best recommended to perform a copy that I know will work without risking a machine due to a corrupted drive? The computer will not be attached to a network, it will be a standalone. Keep in mind these are SCSI drives so I have to use a PCI SCSI converter too, if it is relevant. I have tried Ubuntu, it could not even mount the drives they are so old. All of the drives work as the machines are still running.

Thank you.

Comment: Linux does not support `UFS`, it only supports the UFS variant from BSD-4.4 that introduced incompatible modfcations. Also note that the Solaris UFS implementation does not support byte order abstraction, so you need a Solaris Sparc machine to mount and read the drive.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly the Sparc machines I have available are not able to mount a second hard drive.

Comment: You may create a hd image anywhere and mount that image on a sparc with Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to accomplish, but the best way (I know) to make a backup copy of Solaris installation is to create flash archives:

Build new machine (with linux for example), export via NFS some filesystem, mount on Solaris machine, create flash archives

```
flarcreate -n flash_archive_root -c -R / -x /export/flash.....
```

check archives

```
flar -i /export/flash/inst_x86
```

For more detailed info you can check [my blog post](https://unixswing.blogspot.com/2018/10/install-solaris-from-flash-archive.html) (first part of post)

If you want only to copy the information on them who do not use `rsync` or `scp`

Comment: Thank you. Sadly I need to take all the data in UFS and move it to another drive setup in UFS. My limited searching did not find anything I could use to MAKE a UFS drive. That is what I'm trying to get some help with.

Comment: @Bradley. have you consider downloading Solaris 10 (not 11, not sue of UFS support) and try to create filesystems you need? You will need to read some Solaris documentation because partitioning in Solaris differ a lot from Linux for example

Comment: Until just now I did not know that was an option. Last time we looked the portion of the company that handled our software shut down. If it helps you, the data I need is recipes for Ion Implanters, basically mini particle accelerators. I can get the recipe data and the tuning data. I can make a Solaris drive with the proper release. What I cannot do is put the recipe data and configuration data back on the drive. I don't know much about new versions of Solaris. Would there be a limitation say in the mounting of a SCSI vs a SATA from an OS standpoint?

Comment: @Bradley, the copy of the data (as  I mention in answer) can be done via `ssh`, `rsync`. And there is no difference from Linux. The only difference you will see from point of Solaris about SCSI and PATA/SATA is the name of the device. All the rest from user point of view is the same